# how do I remove a role from a user?

Tags: discord.py

I want to remove a role of a user who removes his reaction and I tried this code but `guild.get_member` return None.

```py
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    for role_id, msg_id, emoji in client.reaction_roles:
        emojiList = str(emoji).split(":")
        emojiName = emojiList[1] 
        if msg_id == payload.message_id and emojiName == payload.emoji.name:
            guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
            member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `discord.utils.get` for this. Here is an example:

```py
guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id="here is the role id")
member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

I'm on mobile so if any syntax or attribute error raises, just comment.

Comment: payload doesn't have a guild or user methods ):

Comment: the third line return NoneType to the member, 
The Error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'`

Comment: Are you sure that this code is in the `on_raw_reaction_remove` event?

Comment: yup I'm sure 
I'm gonna edit and write the whole method.